# C++: Accessing the parent class from a child-class

Tags: c++, class, parent

I have two classes:

```
class ClassA {
    public:
        ClassB *classB;
        int i = 100;
}
// and:
class ClassB {
    public:
        void longProcess();
}
```

I run a void from ClassB():

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
classA->i = 100;
classA->classB = new ClassB();
classB->longProcess(); // it's a long process!
// but when it will finish - I need to get the "i" variable from ClassA
```

How do I get the "int i" variable from the method: longProcess()? Actually, I need to running this long code in another thread that's why I need to retrieve the "i" variable from the ClassB when the longProcess() will finished its work. Any suggestions?

**Update: I try to write some code for saving the pointer to the parent class**

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[ ChildClass.h ]-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
#include "ParentClass.h"
class ChildClass {
    public:
        ChildClass();
        ParentClass *pointerToParentClass; // ERROR: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'ParentClass' with no type
        void tryGet_I_FromParentClass();
};
```

ERROR: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'ParentClass' with no type

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[ ChildClass.cpp ]-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
#include "ChildClass.h"
ChildClass::ChildClass(){}
void ChildClass::tryGet_I_FromParentClass(){
    // this->pointerToParentClass...??? it's not work
}
```

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[ ParentClass.h ]-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
#include "ChildClass.h"
class ParentClass {
    public:
        ParentClass();
        ChildClass *childClass;
        int i;
};
```

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[ ParentClass.cpp ]-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
#include "ParentClass.h"
ParentClass::ParentClass(){
    childClass = new ChildClass();
    childClass->pointerToParentClass = this;
}
```

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[ MainWindow.cpp ]-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
ParentClass *parentClass = new ParentClass();
```

Comment: *Don't* give a variable the same name as the class except for the capitalization of one letter. It will make people want to slap you. People such as me.

Comment: @slashmais, sorry, it's a mistake. It's actually the same class. I've corrected it.

Comment: You seem to be declaring ParentClass in both ChildClass.h and ParentClass.h. Is that intended?

Comment: Yes, I need to call methods in both directions :( from child to parent and from parent to child...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass the `this` pointer from class A (or any pointer to it) to Class B (probably in the constructor) so that it knows where it's contained in, and probably have a member of class B that is pointer-to-A.  Then call the instance method like you would any other.

There's no inheritance here, so some of the other examples wouldn't work.

Edit: Based on your username, I'm guessing you're more familiar with Java?  What you need is a Forward Declaration.  Basically this would be `ChildClass.h`:

```
class ParentClass; // Empty
class ChildClass
{
    ParentClass* myParent;
    // Body omitted
}
```

Ensure that `ChildClass.h` is included at the top of `ParentClass.h` and declare that normally, and include `ParentClass.h` in both .cpp files.  And ensure that all of the implementation of `ChildClass` is in the .cpp file, and the same for `ParentClass` (each in their own, or not, doesn't matter).

What's happening here is that you're creating a circular reference for the compiler, but in `ChildClass.h` all you need is to tell the compiler  "here's a pointer" and that's it.  Thus you don't need the "full size" of the class, thus the "empty" forward declaration is enough.  By the time the .cpp files roll around the compiler "knows" the full size of each, and doesn't throw errors.

See the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/forward-decl.html) for more info on this.

Comment: It's great solution. I tried to do it but my code fails with the error. I've updated the first message.

Comment: Thank you for the link. You really help me! I try to do some testes - and it's work now! Cool :) Thank you! That's really what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If `A::callMeWhenLongProcessFinished()` is actually the only function you every want to call from `B::longProcess()`, you could just pass a pointer to your `A` object to the function:

```
void B::longProcess(A* object) {
    // long process
    object->callMeWhenLongProcessFinished();
}
```

If the setup isn't that trivial, you could instead have `B::longProcess()` take a `std::function<void()>` which is set up to call the proper function and call that instead:

```
void B::longProcess(std::function<void()> callback) {
    // long process
    if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
}

void some_function() {
    A* aptr = get_A_object();
    B* bptr = get_B_object();
    bptr->longProcess(std::bind(&A::callMeWhenLongProcessFinished, aptr));
}
```

Getting the calls being done in different threads will require sending the object around in a suitably thread-safe fashion but this is an entirely separate question.

Comment: I can't pass a pointer... I don't know why but it fails with the error :) (source code is available in the first message)

Comment: If the type isn't known, you need to forward declare it. Since you got a cyclic dependency in the setup you show you need to forward declare at least one of the pointers. You should avoid cyclic dependencies, though. Passing a `std::function<void()>` breaks the dependency cycle nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the parent method at the end of your child method:

```
void ClassB::longProcess() {
  // do your processing
  // ...

  callMeWhenLongProcessHasFinished();
}
```

If, for some bizarre reason, you can't modify `longProcess`, write another method which calls the two methods serially.

Answer (score 0):

You should [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332368%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on ClassB so that ClassA doesn't execute it's method until ClassB is finished.  Alternatively, just call the method from ClassA at the end of ClassB's method.

Comment: But if I run the ClassB in another thread how I can call a method from ClassA?